# Grab Warning and error messages and cast them in a variable with PHP

Tags: php, email, debugging

I've got a cron job and when I run it in terminal it displays some warning: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in `/dbcon.php` on line 116.

I would like to grab the above text and put them into a variable so that I can send it to my email.

What I currently have done is this:

```
//Debugging ...
  if ($this->dbh === false) {
      //Get the warning/error type.....
      $error = error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING);   

      //Get the script name...
      $file = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

      //Get the current file name...
      $class = __FILE__;

      //Send email if the connect() return false...
      $this->process($error, $file, $class);          
  }
```

However, the $error sent to my email is a code. I've also tried error_log() but I couldn't make it work. I also had a look at other SOF 'similar' posts but I did not have any success.

Comment: You could use a library like [Monolog](https://packagist.org/packages/monolog/monolog) that let's you do all kinds of stuff with the errors. A note though, instead of emailing those errors, make sure most of them don't show up. Write the code in such manor that you check for potential issues and handle them correctly. Btw, the `mysql_*`-functions are old, insecure, deprecated in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.0

Comment: I know, but it's old code and I have many cron jobs. The reason I want this functionality is for identifying the error type and go to the file that issues the error/warning and fix it.

Comment: Then I would recommend Monolog. It can email you errors/exceptions, store them in DB, as files and more...

Comment: It would have been nice to get instead of the error code the full warning output: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /dbcon.php on line 116

Comment: Looks like that is exactly what I need.... sweet!!